# Import "hello.views" could not be resolvedPylanceと表示される。

Tags: python3

pythonのウエブウエブサイト制作の基本をテキストに沿って進めていく中でこのような表示がありました。このエラーは何を指摘しているのかが理解できないので教えてほしいです。

Comment: 記述している内容が少なすぎて、何を基にどんな環境で何をやろうとしてどのような問題が発生しているのか、良く分かりません。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に質問内容を改善して特に具体的な情報を詳細に記述してみてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ちなみにメッセージに書かれているPylanceはこちらの記事 [Pythonの新しい言語サーバー「Pylance」がプレビューを卒業 ～「Visual Studio Code」でリッチな開発支援を実現](https://forest.watch.impress.co.jp/docs/news/1324425.html), [Pylanceが既定LSPになったVisual Studio Code用拡張機能「Python」](https://news.mynavi.jp/techplus/article/20210512-1887093/)  のツールでしょうから、参考にした資料に書かれている1つ1つの手順のどれかを抜かしてしまったか、間違えた作業をおこなったかしたのでしょう。あるいは単に何かのタイプミスと言うこともあり得ます。きちんと参考テキストのとおりに作業出来ているか確かめてみてください。

Comment: 類似issueをgithubで探してみたら良いんじゃないすか？https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/236

Comment: PylanceというPythonソースコード入力を支援する機能がimport するhello.views というファイルについて、Pylanceが認識しているファイルパスでは解決できない...という内容ですね。これが出ても実行に問題がないので、なぜなのだろうということですかね？